# Eureka on docker container : unknown host exception

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to start eureka server via spring boot on docker container and getting the following exception "unknownhostexception".
Now in the eureka config.properties file I've used hostname as localhost however the exception is showing that it somehow uses the hostname of the container rather than using the hostname which I've defined in eureka properties file. Moreover even if it uses container defined host name it is resolving fine on container to the right ip and has entry in /etc/hosts.

Note :

1. This is reproducible only if I use oracle java 7/8, however works fine with openjdk 7. Any clues what might be the problem here.

   2. have tried using 127.0.0.1 inplace of localhost in eureka properties without any success.

eureka config file content:

```
# Configure this Discovery Server
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

server:
  port: 1111   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

Exception stack trace:

```
2016-01-11 20:04:54 INFO  RegistrationServer:47 - Starting RegistrationServer v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT with PID 1 (/Jars/registration-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
2016-01-11 20:04:54 INFO  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@70ab4338: startup date [Mon Jan 11 20:04:54 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-11 20:04:55 INFO  AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:153 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-01-11 20:04:55 INFO  Version:27 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
2016-01-11 20:04:55 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:309 - Bean 'encrypt.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.KeyProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-01-11 20:04:55 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:309 - Bean 'encryptionBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58540477] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-01-11 20:04:56 INFO  RegistrationServer:56 - Started RegistrationServer in 2.695 seconds (JVM running for 7.037)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v1.2.4.RELEASE)[0;39m

2016-01-11 20:04:57 INFO  AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@68eefca4: startup date [Mon Jan 11 20:04:57 GMT 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@70ab4338
2016-01-11 20:05:00 WARN  PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:652 - Skipping [/tmp/spring-boot-libs/06f98804e83cf4a94380b46591b976b1d17c36b8-eureka-client-1.1.147.jar] because it does not denote a directory
2016-01-11 20:05:01 WARN  PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:652 - Skipping [/tmp/spring-boot-libs/b8da6470c5c08e33f9ae3737f338b4b81696fa98-eureka-core-1.1.147.jar] because it does not denote a directory
2016-01-11 20:05:04 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:822 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-01-11 20:05:05 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:822 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'infoEndpoint': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=infoEndpoint; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$InfoEndpointRebinderConfiguration; factoryMethodName=infoEndpoint; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration$InfoEndpointRebinderConfiguration.class]]
2016-01-11 20:05:06 INFO  GenericScope:230 - BeanFactory id=0e0ed65b-ca3b-3a06-a0e2-4597f85dabe8
2016-01-11 20:05:06 INFO  AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:153 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-01-11 20:05:07 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:309 - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9787da3e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-01-11 20:05:07 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:309 - Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-01-11 20:05:07 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:309 - Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-01-11 20:05:07 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:309 - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-01-11 20:05:07 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:309 - Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$888ac754] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-01-11 20:05:09 INFO  TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer:79 - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 1111 (http)
2016-01-11 20:05:10 INFO  StandardService:180 - Starting service Tomcat
2016-01-11 20:05:10 INFO  StandardEngine:180 - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2016-01-11 20:05:11 INFO  [/]:180 - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-01-11 20:05:11 INFO  ContextLoader:268 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 14097 ms
2016-01-11 20:05:17 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean:286 - Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-11 20:05:17 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean:286 - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-11 20:05:17 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean:286 - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-11 20:05:17 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean:286 - Mapping filter: 'webRequestTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-11 20:05:17 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean:299 - Mapping filter: 'servletContainer' to urls: [/eureka/*]
2016-01-11 20:05:17 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean:286 - Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-11 20:05:17 INFO  ServletRegistrationBean:188 - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-01-11 20:05:17 INFO  WebApplicationImpl:785 - Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.13 06/29/2012 05:14 PM'
2016-01-11 20:05:28 ERROR EurekaInstanceConfigBean:122 - Cannot get host info
java.net.UnknownHostException: ef769e37c05f: ef769e37c05f: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaInstanceConfigBean.initHostInfo(EurekaInstanceConfigBean.java:118)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaInstanceConfigBean.<init>(EurekaInstanceConfigBean.java:50)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.eurekaInstanceConfigBean(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2debd82d.CGLIB$eurekaInstanceConfigBean$3(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2debd82d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a2b83124.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2debd82d.eurekaInstanceConfigBean(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.cisco.microservice.registration.RegistrationServer.main(RegistrationServer.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ef769e37c05f: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471)
    ... 50 more
2016-01-11 20:05:28 WARN  URLConfigurationSource:120 - No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-01-11 20:05:28 INFO  URLConfigurationSource:121 - To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2016-01-11 20:05:28 INFO  DynamicPropertyFactory:281 - DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@69f889
2016-01-11 20:05:29 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:517 - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@68eefca4: startup date [Mon Jan 11 20:04:57 GMT 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@70ab4338
2016-01-11 20:05:29 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[//lastn],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.lastn(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2016-01-11 20:05:29 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.status(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2016-01-11 20:05:29 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-01-11 20:05:29 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-01-11 20:05:29 INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:314 - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-01-11 20:05:29 INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:314 - Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-01-11 20:05:29 INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:314 - Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/metrics],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/trace],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/health],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/configprops],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/refresh],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/pause],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/autoconfig],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/mappings],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/env],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/env/reset],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.reset()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/restart],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/archaius],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/dump],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/env],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/beans],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  EndpointHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/resume],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  SpringTemplateLoader:61 - SpringTemplateLoader for FreeMarker: using resource loader [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@68eefca4: startup date [Mon Jan 11 20:04:57 GMT 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@70ab4338] and template loader path [classpath:/templates/]
2016-01-11 20:05:32 INFO  FreeMarkerConfigurer:127 - ClassTemplateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration
2016-01-11 20:05:33 WARN  URLConfigurationSource:120 - No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  URLConfigurationSource:121 - To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:431 - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:912 - Bean with name 'refreshEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:912 - Bean with name 'restartEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:912 - Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:912 - Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:912 - Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:674 - Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:674 - Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:674 - Located managed bean 'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:674 - Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=68eefca4,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:674 - Located managed bean 'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  EndpointMBeanExporter:431 - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  DefaultLifecycleProcessor:341 - Starting beans in phase 0
2016-01-11 20:05:33 INFO  EurekaConfigBasedInstanceInfoProvider:80 - Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
^C^C2016-01-11 20:05:35 INFO  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:862 - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@70ab4338: startup date [Mon Jan 11 20:04:54 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
^C^C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved by adding following work around in the docker file:

```
# Fix DNS resolution issues when nss is not installed
RUN echo 'hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4' >> /etc/nsswitch.conf

# Set DNS cache to 10 seconds (Cache is permanent by default). Network hosts are volatile in Docker clusters.
RUN grep '^networkaddress.cache.ttl=' /opt/${JAVA_PACKAGE}/jre/lib/security/java.security || echo 'networkaddress.cache.ttl=10' >> /opt/${JAVA_PACKAGE}/jre/lib/security/java.security
```